# Render Text with MetalKit

Tags: swift, text, uiview, metalkit

Is there a way to render Text in MetalKit ?

I have found this [Link](http://metalbyexample.com/rendering-text-in-metal-with-signed-distance-fields/) (in Obj.C and iOS8) and I am wondering if there is a more up-to-date example that shows MetalKit Text rendering in Swift ?

What could also help is how to render an UIView into MetalKit. Does anybody know of an example to that ?

Comment: Hi, did to find some thing useful?

Comment: nope - nothing so far....